# Is there any sorted set that not allow to add equals elements and keep them sorted by predefined comporator?

Tags: java, sorting, sortedset

I need a collection, that will not be able to keep element, that `equals()` to each other, and than, they must be sorted in such a collection at any time by predefined comprator

For example:

```
public static class Token {
    public Long id;
    public String valueForCompare;

    public Token(Long id, String valueForCompare) {
        this.id = id;
        this.valueForCompare = valueForCompare;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        Token token = (Token) o;
        return Objects.equals(id, token.id);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id);
    }
}

@Test
public void test() {
    Set<Token> tokens = new SomeSetThatIAskFor<>();
    tokens.add(new Token(1L, "first token"));
    tokens.add(new Token(2L, "second token"));

    Assert.assertEquals(tokens.size(), 2);

    tokens.add(new Token(2L, "third token"));

    Assert.assertEquals(tokens.size(), 2);
    Assert.assertEquals(
            tokens.get(new Token(2L, "no_matter_to_get_from_collection_value")).valueForCompare,
            "second token");

    tokens.add(new Token(3L, "third token"));

    Assert.assertEquals(tokens.size(), 3);
    Assert.assertEquals(
            tokens.get(new Token(3L, "no_matter_to_get_from_collection_value")).valueForCompare,
            "third token");
}
```

So, i need, to `tokens` contains all elements sorted at all time, that it present

And at the same time, i need, that `tokens` not contain any elements that are `equals()` to other elements

If i use `TreeSet`, than i cant add two elements, that `compare` return 0, and they are not equals, than it will remove them too

I need collection, where equality of each element defines by `equals()` method, and order of elements defines by `compare()` method

Is there any existed collection, or i must define it by myself?

(answer with example, please)

Comment: TreeSet has a constructor where you can supply a custom comperator for sorting. And as a Set it doesn't allow duplicates (checked by equals) just like all Sets don't allow duplicates.

Comment: If i use TreeSet, than i cant add two elements, that compare return 0, and they are not equals, than it will remove them too

I need, to keep elements, that compare method return 0

Comment: What exactly are you saying there?

Comment: I need collection, that allow to keep any comparable elements, whatever compare method return. And in what will not present any equals elements.

Comment: ...so you want a set.  A set won't keep duplicates (so your second requirement is satisfied), and you can order them like with SortedSet or TreeSet.  You've effectively answered your own question there.

Comment: you can use `List` and manage duplicates and sorting yourself (own class). `Set` will not work ("*sets contain no pair of elements `e1` and `e2` such that `e1.equals(e2)`*")

Comment: @Makoto TreeSet not allow to add elements, that compare method return o, and equals method return false. But i need such a collection

Comment: @user15244370, so the answer, is that there is no such a collection, that i need? Yes? Can you please provide answer

Comment: @Bestows You could try write the Comparator in a way that he only returns 0 if the objects are equal. eG. First check if the 2 objects are equal and if they are return 0. If they are not do your own compare logic and calculate if you would return -1, 0 or +1. Then if you would return 0 instead do another calculation and return for example the comparision of the hashCode of the objects. I'm going to have to say this sounds however quiet unclean and I'm not sure if a comparator like this would not break the contract that it needs to follow. Creating your own custom class is probably cleaner

Comment: **Your collection does not make sense to me.**  You don't want to add duplicate elements (sets do this), and can keep comparable elements (sets do this too).  If you use a Comparator, you can just compare based on `hashCode` as opposed to `equals` if you wanted to (and...sets allow this behavior).

Comment: So in what order should such elements be then (if the comparator regards them as equal, but the set doesn't)?